# Woocommerce stock update via DB don't save variations in front

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-variations

we have a script to update stock of products variations each 2 hours :

```
// Database settings
$db="*********";
$dbhost="*********";
$dbport=*********;
$dbuser="*********";
$dbpasswd="*********";

echo "Connection à la base de donnée $dbhost:$dbport\n";
try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';port='.$dbport.';dbname='.$db.'', $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection impossible !\n $e";
    return;
}
echo "Connection réussie !\n";
if ($handle = opendir("/*********/*********/*********/stock")) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                $path = "/*********/*********/*********/*********/$entry";
                if(is_dir($path)) continue;
                if(strtoupper(substr($entry, 0, 4)) != "STKT") continue;

                //Get number of lines
                echo "Traitement du fichier $entry\n";
                $totalLines = intval(exec("wc -l '$path'"));
                if (($handle2 = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($csvContent = fgetcsv($handle2,10000,";")) !== FALSE) {
                        // now $csvContent should contain an array with each item in the CSV row

                        echo "Mise à jour du stock de {$csvContent[1]}\n";
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE wp_wc_product_meta_lookup SET stock_quantity = ? where sku = ?");
                        $stmt->bindParam(1,$csvContent[2]);
                        $stmt->bindParam(2,$csvContent[1]);
                        try{
                            $stmt->execute();
                        } catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo "La requête n'a pas pu être executé pour le SKU $csvContent[1] sur la table wp_wc_product_meta_lookup !\n {$e->getMessage()}\n";
                        }

                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = ? WHERE post_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM wp_wc_product_meta_lookup WHERE sku = ?) AND meta_key = '_stock';");
                        $stmt->bindParam(1,$csvContent[2]);
                        $stmt->bindParam(2,$csvContent[1]);
                        try{
                            $stmt->execute();
                        } catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo "Requête n'a pas pu être executé pour le SKU $csvContent[1] sur la table wp_postmeta !\n{$e->getMessage()}\n";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "Le fichier à bien été traité.\n";
                    fclose($handle2);
                    copy($path, "/*********/*********/*********/*********/*********/$entry");
                    unlink($path);
                }
            }
    }
```

Everthing is updating fine in the back office I can see that stock are correct, but they are not showing good in front.
If I go manually in the backoffice and re save the product, the good stock is showing in frontend.

I think Iam missing something... is there a way the resave all product ? or maybe another way to make it work ?

thank ou in advance for your help ! :)

R

desacivate all plugins, search for cache issues...

Comment: My initial assumption would be that your products are cached on the frontend. When you save the product from the backend, you're clearing the cache.

Comment: I tried to deactivate all cache / cdn etc and nothing happen...

Comment: It could be cached via transients located in the wp_options table

Comment: Some hosts use aggressive caching which you won't be able to override. Have you considered making these updates via the API instead? If not, could you fire off a WP CLI command to clear the cache that way? I'd be inclined to write this as a task that runs within WordPress. It'll be much easier to programatically update products in a way that clears the cache rather than reaching into the DB manually.